# How to write my own x and y label for a figure?

Tags: floats

I have a figure that I want to write the x and y label for both subfigures in latex after i include the figures. How do I do it?

here is an example

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{figures/ablation/plot.pdf}

\caption{}
\label{fig:ablation}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is use TikZ node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,
           label=west:\rotatebox{90}{$y$ label},
           label=below:$x$ label]
           {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};

\caption{}
\label{fig:ablation}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]